# need info for preg_match_all

Tags: php, regex, preg-match, preg-match-all

> 2, 19, 32, 43, 44, Str1. 1, 2 Str2. 2, 3

i wanna cut this string

Part 1 : 2, 19,32, 43, 44
Part 2 : 1, 2
Part 3 : 2, 3

tanks for help.

Comment: Would you reconsider how you are storing this data?  That seems quite an awful solution.  I recommend JSON.

Answer (score 1):

You want to split, not to match. Therefore use [`preg_split`](http://php.net/preg_split)

```
 $parts = preg_split('/Str\d+\./', $source);
```

Answer (score 0):

`preg_match_all("/(.*), Str1\. (.*) Str2\. (.*)/")`

Comment: `preg_match_all("/(.*), $Str1\. (.*) $Str2\. (.*)/")`